Forming a question over a direct object of a ditransitive verb
This is a complement to my previous question. I chose a slightly fictional sentence where the same question word corresponds to a direct object and an indirect object. It's because I'm also interested how someone distinguishes whether the question is about a direct object or an indirect object.
Source sentence:

I gave an ogre a child.

Which of the following interrogative sentences are correct?

Who did I give an ogre?

or

Who did I give to an ogre?

The first variant above means either that the ogre is given or that the ogre receives. If the first variant is correct, then how does someone distinguish these meanings?

I gave an ogre a child would be understood to mean that the child was given to the ogre. For the reverse meaning, say to a child.

"Who did I give an ogre?" doesn't sound very natural to me - I'd prefer "Who did I give an ogre to?" or "Who did I give to an ogre?" That doesn't mean the original is ungrammatical, but you've proven it's less clear than my alternatives.

This question is similar to: Forming a question over an indirect object. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It's the same structure as your previous question and is therefore a duplicate.

@Lambie, my previous question is about indirect objects.

This question has the same structure as the other one. I gave you a cookie. I gave a cookie to you. has the same structure as: I gave a child to an ogre. I gave an ogre a child. So, the question follows the same pattern as the other question. One is about a cookie and the other a child but it's the same grammar.

@Lambie, I already answered, but you ignore nuances.

You need the preposition "to" to show direction.

Who did I give an ogre (someone has been given to the ogre)
To who did I give an ogre (an ogre has been given to someone)

It's also common to put the preposition at the end of the sentence (ie "Who did I give an ogre to?")
The same is true of the more formal 'whom', unless "whom" is the direct object of the verb (and not the object of a preposition).
